# RDFS: subClassOf, type, and "multiple inheritance."

Tags: object, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

**The Setup**

Consider a design where I have a 2 executable programs, `foo` and `bar`.  Assume both are a subClassOf `SW` e.g. (and dropping most prefixing for clarity):

```
SW   rdf:type  rdfs:Class

foo   rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo   rdfs:subClassOf  SW

bar   rdf:type  rdfs:Class
bar   rdfs:subClassOf  SW
```

SPARQLing with the Jena default reasoner does the expected thing so you can, for example, ask for all things of subClassOf `SW` and get foo and bar, and you can get all the properties of the super/subclasses, etc.  OK.  Consider foo and bar to be "atoms"; that is, there is only one each of them.   But they could be deployed multiple times.  How do we well-segregate the atom info from the per-instance info?  Initially, one might try "single inheritance"; here are two such instances of `foo`:

```
foo_111  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_111  rdfs:subClassOf  foo
foo_222  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_222  rdfs:subClassOf  foo
```

The problem is now when we ask for all our software atoms (`SW`) we also pick up the instances thereof which is not what we want.  It is probably possible to filter out instances in some way.  One way might be with a "marker class", sort of like multiple inheritance:

```
foo_111  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_111  rdfs:subClassOf  foo
foo_111  rdfs:subClassOf  Instance
foo_222  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_222  rdfs:subClassOf  foo
foo_222  rdfs:subClassOf  Instance
```

and the query would filter anything of type Instance.

Let's keep exploring for the moment.

An alternate approach is to have an Instance be its own class and have a field named `exec` which references the thing being activated as a Instance:

```
Instance  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_111  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_111  rdfs:subClassOf  Instance
foo_111  exec             foo
foo_222  rdf:type  rdfs:Class
foo_222  rdfs:subClassOf  Instance
foo_222  exec             foo
```

This is tidy because is cleanly separates the "atom" space from the "instance" space and all sorts of things can become instances.   **But** :  Now it seems I cannot SPARQL for all my `SW`, e.g.

```
?s rdfs:subClassOf Instance ;
        exec       SW .
```

I'm not really surprised because the type/subClassOf machinery isn't looking for a property called `exec` to work the magic.   Note that SPECIFIC values for exec work fine, e.g.

```
?s rdfs:subClassOf Instance ;
        exec       foo .
```

But that is of course way too restrictive/specific; we cannot name every possible piece of software.

**The Question**

Are there any design best practices in this space that make simple things simple (e.g. "find all SW atoms that EOL in 180 days", which if it yielded 6 pieces of software, we don't want to drag in the 12000 instances of those 6 pieces of software).

Comment: Are you describing actual individuals with foo_111, or are you describing a second level of subclasses? The snippets of RDF shown are representing subclasses, in which case what you're after seems to be a way of selecting direct subclasses only; however if you mean individuals, the snippets are wrong - should have `rdf:type` rather than `rdfs:subClassOf`

Comment: I did try  
    "foo_111  rdf:type  foo"
but that leads to same issue where the instances (foo_111) get caught up the query for the atoms (foo).   In other words, looking for all SW still picks up foo_111.  You're right, though; foo_111 is def NOT a true subclass of foo; it is an instance of it.

Comment: NOTE:  With fresh eyes and a few more experiments based on a nudge from @Ignazio I believe I now have a working solution.   foo_111 is an rdf:type of foo but also subClassOf  Instance.   I can now ask for instances or atoms of both specific types and supertypes.

Answer (score 2):

Your conceptualization is incorrect. An object is either a concept (class) or an individual, and it depends on the *granularity* of your knowledge base. In this case, SW is a class, foo and bar are subclasses of SW, and foo_111 and foo_222 are individuals of the foo class. Do not create the class Instance. Instead, use the rdf:type predicate to instantiate the software tools, and use the rdfs:subclassOf predicate in the SPARQL filter to find all software tools. If you need to query instances, use a datatype property to capture a unique identifier, say the barcode of particular copies of the software, and query the value of that property.

Comment: Yes, in the end "Instance" was superfluous.